# What is the difference between import * as react from 'react' vs import react from 'react'

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React or the coding background in general. And I am not sure what is the difference between the statements

```
import * as react from 'react'
```

and

```
import react from 'react'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 45):

There are 3 types of most import commonly used imports.

**Type 1**

```
import * as A from 'abc';
```

This will import everything which is marked as export in abc. You can access them using below code.

```
A.Component
```

**Type 2**

```
import {A} from 'abc';
```

This will import A from abc, containing something like this:

```
export const A = () => {};
```

**Type 3**

```
import A from 'abc';
```

This will import the default export from abc as A. The export can look like this:

```
const B = () => {}; // The name "B" is not exported, only the value.

export default B;  // at the end of component
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks. Type 3 isn't clear to me. I `import` `A` but then ain't I overriding it by declaring `const A =....`?  Is the `export` statement in the `component` which is importing `A` or which initially imported `A`? Also, in type 2, Does `A` need to be a function (`()=>{...}` or could it be an object as well `export const A={}`?

Comment: object as well. For this import A from 'abc'; import syntax export like this export default A;

Answer (score 18):

Pattern `import * as React from 'react` is related to the use of type systems in React like Flow or Typescript. Using `import React from 'react'` has led to issues with importing types definitions. For now in Typescript you can use `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag, which resolves this issue and imports all types even if you use `import React from 'react'`.

Comment: Or simply use create_react_app which already solved this issue and let's `import React from 'react'` even with typescript.

Answer (score 14):

In general, for ES2015 (ES6) modules

```
import * as name from 'module';
```

is a namepace import that indicates that all exported objects are to be placed in the name namespace. You can then do:

```
name.blabla1
name.blabla2
etc ...
```

The namespace is not callable. So you cannot do:

```
name();
```

While:

```
import name from 'module';
```

is a default import that is equivalent to:

```
import {default as name} from 'module';
```

You're importing only the default object from the module.

In the case of React, the confusion maybe/probably arises from the fact that React's default export is ... React (Babel adds the default export for interoperability reasons). Strictly speaking, the syntax to use is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

or

```
import {Whatever} from 'react';
```

The following work only because of the transformation by Babel (not 100% sure):

```
import React from 'react';
import React, { Whatever } from 'react';
```

For those using TypeScript, prior to version 2.7, the default was to treat:

```
import * as name from 'module';
```

as being equivalent to:

```
const name = require('module');
```

and:

```
import name from 'module';
```

as being equivalent to:

```
const name = require('module').default;
```

Since version 2.7, if your compiler settings specify "esModuleInterop" to true (which is recommended), then you can use the ES2015 syntax behavior.