# How to import React in TypeScript (.tsx) the right way™?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Thoughout our TSX/React web application, we use two different import style for the `react` module:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

and

```
import React from "react"
```

I am not aware of any functional difference between the two. Both work just fine. Is there any reason to prefer one notion over the other?

Comment: That totally depends. In the case of `React` both work fine as all the classes and methods are exported from the package along with combine `export default`. If a package doesn't export `default` then you will need to `import * as package`, so that you can have all the exported methods as an object.

Comment: @SonuBamniya Thanks. I'm aware of the difference in general but asking for the react package specifically.

Comment: Alright! I think you should give a read to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285737/import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-from-react)

Comment: @SonuBamniya Amazing, my question has been answered there. My question might even be considered a duplicate. Could you convert that into an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @JaredSmith, yes, thanks. This is the link Sonu posted as well.

Comment: @SimonWarta I voted to close your question as a duplicate of the other which causes the system automatically add the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do `import React from "react"` so you editor can auto change it to  `import React, { useState } from "react"`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting point. I tried `import * as React, { useState } from "react";` which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge both are same.

import everything from "react"  and then we can use it as React in our application

```
  import * as React from "react";
```

same as

```
 import React from "react";
```

So as per me you need to use **import React from "react";**.Because you can directly access React from react npm.