# import * as React tree shaking?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, optimization, tree-shaking

> import * as React from ‘react’

I’m using flow types and importing React like this is recommended. My question is does this have tree shaking implications? Is this importing more than I need and increasing my js file sizes?

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285737/import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-from-react