# Named export 'Types' not found. The requested module 'mongoose' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, commonjs, ecmascript-2020

I have an express server written in typescript with `"module": "es2020"` in its tsconfig.

I've also developed another `es2020` module for my graphql API, still in typescript, and this module uses mongoose with such named imports:

```js
import { Types } from 'mongoose'
```

Everything works fine when I compile my graphql module with `tsc`. But the express server which is ran with

`nodemon --watch './**/*.ts' --exec 'node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm' src/index.ts`

is unable to handle the mongoose named import.

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Types' not found. The requested module 'mongoose' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'mongoose';
const { Types } = pkg;
```

#### Solution #1

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

And replace `Types` by `mongoose.Types`.

But since `tsc` can handle the mongoose named import, I have hope that it's also possible to make ts-node able to do so.

#### Solution #2

Switch to `commonjs`, I can keep the import/export syntax in my graphql module and compile it as a cjs module. But I would have to use a cjs syntax in my express server, and I don't want to.

Comment: Even though @types/mongodb says it's deprecated, I still use the package and can then use named imports.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Adding `@types/mongodb` to my module won't make me able to use mongoose named import with ts-node, btw I'm not only importing `Types` from mongoose, in some other files I'm importing `Schema` and `Model`. And I'm facing the same error

Comment: @Ashitaka did you find a solution?

Comment: @MrPablo I didn't find a real solution, so I've chosen to build my express server with `tsc` before running it with node, which works fine, but I have to rebuild and start the server after each modification

Answer (score 29):

### TL;DR

All you have to do is remove the curly braces from the Types. That should work. Just like this:

```
import Types from 'mongoose'
```

But the name does not matter.

### Explanation

`import Types from 'mongoose'` works because we are importing the package's default export (this is why the name we use does not matter).

However, when you do `import * as Types from 'mongoose` you tell JS that you *seriously* want everything as it is raw. That means that instead of getting the default export:

```json
{
    "function1": {},
    "function2": {}
}
```

You get this:

```json
{
    "default": {
        "function1": {},
        "function2": {}
    }
}
```

So you could have also done `Types.default` but that's probably not as clean.

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285737/import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-from-react) suggests that we could make both work, but also suggests it would be a hacky workaround that probably should not work

Comment: What is the import statement is causing the issue is within node_modules (ie. external libraries)?

Comment: This answer explains some differences in import statements but it doesn't address the question asked in any way. This is a specific error thrown when trying to import what amounts to a CommonJS named export _by name_ using a module import statement. `tsc` handles this fine, ts-node with Jest handles this fine, but ts-node by itself seems to fail working with these imports and this quesiton is asking why that is.

Answer (score 8):

If you encounter this error having a mono-repo, make sure the module that you have problems with, has

```
"type": "module"
```

in `package.json`.

It seems that Nodejs will consider packages to be `commonjs` by default and you need to explicitly tell it that your package is a module.