# Usage of enums outside-of-tsconfig-context as values - NodeJS,

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, monorepo

We have a TS monorepo structure, including `frontend`, `backend` and `models` directories in the root. Directory `models` consists of reusable data models and enums.

Backend is built using NodeJS (Typescript) and Express. We are using `ts-node` for local development.

**The problem**: When using those enums as types from the `models` directory inside the `backend` directory, everything works fine. But, when using those enums **as values**, we are getting the following error:

```
import { Projects } from '../../../../models/enums/projects.enum';
         ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Projects' not found. The requested module '../../../../models/enums/projects.enum' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '../../../../models/enums/projects.enum';
const { Projects } = pkg;
```

`backend` `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/typings"],
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "db/knexfile.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "files": ["src/typings/index.d.ts"]
}
```

Why does this happen? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the declaration of the enum you are trying to import?

Comment: It's a standard export:

`export enum Projects { EXAMPLE = "EXAMPLE" }`

Comment: From my last experience Typescript enums in a nx monorepo where a hustle to share, especially when the libs have to be built before usage and are for example used via npm workspaces. I would recommend to use types instead. They will give you autocompletion and safety if used correctly. But this won't answer your question, so check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605320/named-export-types-not-found-the-requested-module-mongoose-is-a-commonjs-mo