# import ReactDOM vs. import { ReactDOM }

Tags: reactjs

May be a stupid question.

```
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom/client'; // or import {ReactDOM as ReactDOM} are BAD
...
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
```

received error:

> export 'ReactDOM' (imported as 'ReactDOM') was not found in
> 'react-dom/client' (possible exports: createRoot, hydrateRoot)

OK only `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';`  This is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285737/import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-from-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question, but assuming I'm on point, the difference is how they are exported from the package.

ReactDOM is `export default` whereas the others (`createRoot`, `hydrateRoot`) are `export` only.

For more info:
[`export const` vs. `export default` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

(and based on the fact that post has over 290 upvotes - not a silly question at all)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```js
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
```

as this is current syntax to import it .

Answer (score 0):

***To fix the issue, simply modify your import statement for createRoot to look like this:***

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
```

Your code Should be like:

```
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).