# ESLint No default export found in imported module "react"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

## Problem

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
```

I turn on `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in `tsconfig.json`.
And I also use `eslint-import-plugin` and `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` for linting about import.

But, eslint says "`No default export found in imported module "react".`"

How to fix this?

## Background

### Tech Stack

- react: 18.2.0
- @types/react: 18.0.14
- typescript: 4.7.4
- eslint: 8.18
- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin: 5.30
- @typescript-eslint/parser: 5.30.5
- eslint-import-resolver-typescript: 3.1.1
- eslint-plugin-import: 2.26
- eslint-plugin-react: 7.30
  ...

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@custom-types/*": ["custom-types/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@constants": ["constants.ts"],
      "@api/*": ["api/*"],
      "@context/*": ["context/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["src/custom-types"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

### .eslintrc.json

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2022": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "project": "frontend/tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never",
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: No direct solution to your problem, but since React 18, importing react is not necessary.

Comment: Can you show us your package.json? Do you have `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` installed as a devDependency?

I was running into the same issue. Ensuring these were installed resolved my issue.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285991/5289334) explains why.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` fixed my problem.

```
import * as React from 'react';
```