# how to install Quill.js in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, quill

Sorry, my understanding of how packaging works in `Angular` is terrible!! I want to use a `WYSIWYG` editor in my `Angular6` application. I have zeroed down to `quill.js`. https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/

But I am confused how I can include it in my project. I have added it as a dependency in my `package.json`.

```
  "dependencies": {
...
    "quill": "1.3.6"
  }
```

and then I tried to use for the following `textarea`

```
<textarea id="question-description" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="questionDescription" [ngClass]="validateField('questionDescription')"  rows="4"></textarea>
```

and initialize `Quill` like following in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
var quill = new Quill('#question-description', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

But I get error

```
ReferenceError: Quill is not defined
    at NewPracticeQuestionComponent.push../s
```

I have also added `declare var Quill:any;` at the top of the Component's `.ts` file

I can see in `node_modules` that there is a `quill` folder and it has `dist/quill.js` where I suppose `Quill` object must be defined and exported (haven't checked it though).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Follow** these simple steps to install quilljs in **Angular** application

Install the below packages

`npm install quill`
`npm install ngx-quill`
`npm install @types/quill`

Add the **below css files** in `angular.json` file.

```
"styles": ["./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
    "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
    "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
    "src/styles.css",
]
```

Add the **below module** in `app.module.ts` file under

```
`QuillModule.forRoot({
      customOptions: [{
        import: 'formats/font',
        whitelist: ['mirza', 'roboto', 'aref', 'serif', 'sansserif', 'monospace']
      }]
})`
```

Add the **below code** in `app.component.html`

```
<quill-editor [styles]="{height: '200px'}"></quill-editor>
```

I have created [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quilljs-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html) demo here.

Answer (score 2):

This linked helped (https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/777). I had to add the following lines, however I don't really understand well how it works and what the steps mean

```
 import * as Quill from 'Quill';

let quill = new Quill('#editor');
```

Comment: the explanation here was helpful -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585763/what-is-the-difference-between-import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-fr

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [ngx-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill) wrapper.

Comment: I'll give `ngx-quill` a try. I need validation feature `forms` as some of my `wysiwyg` editors are part of the form. But I am unable to make it work with `Quill`. I might seek your help as I am sure to get stuck! :)

Comment: I tried to use `ngx-quill` but am getting error. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140987/error-quill-module-ts-is-missing-from-the-typescript-compilation-please-make

Answer (score 1):

Thanks the answer from Sathiamoorthy. That helps me a lot.
I want to add more comments here during my quill setup.
Since my Angular CLI version is 12.0. I have to identify the specific version to make it work. (I spent 6 hours to figure this out)

Like:

npm install quill@**1.3.7**

npm install ngx-quill@**13.0.1**

npm install @types/quill@**1.3.10**

Hope this helps the people still in frustration.

Comment: You should add this as a comment on the accepted answer instead, so that all the requisite information is contained in one answer.

Comment: I haven't got my 50 reputation point to add a comment on the accepted answer. ：）

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32342467)