# React default import errors in NextJS project with TypeScript, esModuleInterop=true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, es6-modules

My TypeScript config in my Next.js app is not happy with this trivial import:

```
import React from 'react'
```

Granted, Next.js imports React by default into global, but that leads to another warning. Adding the import seems clearer, so assume I'm stubborn on this point.

The error:

```
TS1259: Module '"~/my-project/node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag  index.d.ts(65, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

But I already have `esModuleInterop: true`:

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,  //  <==================== Right here
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I expected the error to take into account my config. So why am I getting this error?

**Edit:**

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

doesn't error, so I can move forward. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585795/152543) provides details. This still leaves the question why default import won't work (which seems to be the preferred in the community).