# When saying import React from 'react'; where is React imported from?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

There seems to be no corresponding folder or file named 'react'. Maybe using npm start gives the JSX file access to 'react', I don't know where 'react' is located though.

Basically, where is 'react' located?

I looked in the node_modules folder, and there is a subfolder named react. However, there is no file named React in there.

import React from 'react';

In the above line of code, I can not figure out where React is. I tried looking in the 'react' folder that is a subfolder of node_modules

Comment: You might want to check this whole [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585763/what-is-the-difference-between-import-as-react-from-react-vs-import-react-fr), could be useful.

Comment: @ivanatias I took a look but found nothing as to where 'react' is located.

Answer (score 0):

`React` is exported from the [React package](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react).

```js
import React from 'react';
```

In the above line, you are importing a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import). You can give it any name you want instead of `React`.

In the `React` source code you can find this default export defined in [package.json](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fabef7a6b71798fe2477720e59d090a0e74e0009/packages/react/package.json#L25).

Answer (score 0):

The word `React` is where you assigned whatever the 'react' library exported as default.

if you open the `node_modules/react/package.json` file and check it you can find following line of code,

```
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "react-server": "./react.shared-subset.js",
      "default": "./index.js" // <----------------------------- see here
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./jsx-runtime": "./jsx-runtime.js",
    "./jsx-dev-runtime": "./jsx-dev-runtime.js"
  },
```

The package.json says the entry point is `index.js` so if you check the content of `index.js`, (exports["."]["default"] says use `index.js` for default import ( ie `import DefaultReact from 'react'` ))

```
'use strict';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
}
```

This is not just a react specific thing, you can learn how to create custom packages from [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).